# react does not re-render on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this functional component:

```
const PriorityInput = () => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState({
    taskPriorityLow: false,
    taskPriorityMedium: false
  });

  const onPriorityClick = name => {
    Object.keys(isActive).forEach(key =>
      key === name ? setIsActive({ ...isActive, [key]: true }) : setIsActive({ ...isActive, [key]: false })
    );
  };

  return (
     <div className="task-priority-input-container">
        <label className="task-priority-input-label">Priority</label>
        <span
          className={
            isActive.taskPriorityLow
              ? "task-priority-button task-priority-low-active"
              : "task-priority-button task-priority-low"
          }
          onClick={() => onPriorityClick("taskPriorityLow")}
        >
          LOW
        </span>
<span
          className={
            isActive.taskPriorityLow
              ? "task-priority-button task-priority-medium-active"
              : "task-priority-button task-priority-medium"
          }
          onClick={() => onPriorityClick("taskPriorityMedium")}
        >
          MEDIUM
        </span>
      </div>
  );
};

export default TaskForm;
```

however when I click on the `span` its style does not change.

From similar questions I understood that calling `setIsActive()` with spread object would trigger a rerender.

Comment: Your span doesn't have `name` prop assigned. So I don't think you are getting the correct value in the `onPriorityClick `. Can you give `name='taskPriorityLow''` to span and try it?

Comment: Why `Object.keys`? You can just set `taskPriorityLow` directly by calling `setIsActive`. `setIsActive({[name]: !isActive[name]})`

Comment: I created a sandbox and found the classname has been updated properly. Couldn't reproduce your probelm https://codesandbox.io/s/black-breeze-73yv2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jan.
I think it's not necessary foreach statement.

trying to do like this.

```js
const PriorityInput = () => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState({
    taskPriorityLow: false,
    taskPriorityMedium: false,
    taskPriorityHigh: false,
  });

  const onPriorityClick = name => {
    console.log("clicked - ", name);
    const updateActive = {...isActive};
    Object.keys(isActive).forEach(key => {
      if(key === name)
        updateActive[key] = true;
      else
        updateActive[key] = false;
    });
    
    setIsActive(updateActive);
  };

  return (
     <div className="container">
        <label className="input-label">Priority</label>
        <span
          className={
            isActive.taskPriorityLow
              ? "btn btn-primary"
              : "btn btn-secondary"
          }
          onClick={() => onPriorityClick("taskPriorityLow")}
        >
          LOW
        </span>
        <span
          className={
            isActive.taskPriorityMedium
              ? "btn btn-primary"
              : "btn btn-secondary"
          }
          onClick={() => onPriorityClick("taskPriorityMedium")}
        >
          MEDIUM
        </span>
        <span
          className={
            isActive.taskPriorityHigh
              ? "btn btn-primary"
              : "btn btn-secondary"
          }
          onClick={() => onPriorityClick("taskPriorityHigh")}
        >
          HIGH
        </span>
      </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<PriorityInput />, rootElement);
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I've edited the question. I used the ForEach, because in my original code I have multiple span elements. I've added one more to justify the forEach and clarify its use.

Comment: In my code, I have added multiple span elements also. could you explain more details for the fixing?

Comment: wouldn't `setIsActive({ ...isActive, [name]: !isActive[name] });` only change the element that you clicked to switch between `active` and  `!active`? the point is to set other elements to `!active` and the one you clicked to `active`.

Comment: I have updated the answer. and anyway you shouldn't use `setIsActive` on foreach statement. because `setState` is async function. also setIsActive is async function. you called async function multiple times before finish the one call, so the workflow was broken.

Comment: That did it, I thought it was related to async... thanks. I marked your answer

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
Object.keys(isActive).forEach(key =>
  key === name ? setIsActive({ ...isActive, [key]: true }) : setIsActive({ ...isActive, [key]: false })
);
```

directly you can write

```
setIsActive({ ...isActive, [name]: true })
```

this should help.

Comment: if you checking explicitly then use conditional operator